# Break on attribute modifications not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

I would like to check which js changed an element using DevTools, but I don't know how.
I right-clicked on the element and added Break on attribute modifications, but there was no response.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
// myPulgin.js
;(function($) {
  $.fn.myPulgin = function(options) {
    const defaults = {
      name: 'foo',
      color: '#ff0000'
    };

    const {
      name,
      color
    } = $.extend(defaults, options);

    $(this).text(name);
    $(this).css({
      color
    })

    return this;
  };
})(jQuery);
</script>

<script>
// index.js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.target').myPulgin({
    name: 'bar'
  });
});
</script>

<div class="target"></div>
```

### Remove style and set breakpoint on target

[image]

### Adding a debugger statement to the beginning of the body/script

[image]

Comment: You need to set a breakpoint before the change occurs. If I remove style and set breakpoint on target and then run your code - the breakpoint gets triggered as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I deleted the style and set a breakpoint, but there was no response.

Comment: instead of refreshing the page after setting breakpoint copy-paste the JS code and put it into devtools console

Comment: Thank you for your instruction. What if you don't know which js is changing the element?

Comment: `$(this).css({color})` this js only changing the elelemnt

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I don't know the details of myPulgin.js, is there a way to find out about it via devtool?

Comment: Honestly I think your original approach should work, it might be some Chrome bug. You might get more luck by pressing pause in debugger as soon as page loads, or adding a `debugger` statement to the beginning of the body/script. Consider reporting this to Chrome bug tracker

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So it could be a bug :'-(

Comment: Thank you for your instruction.I got more luck when I added a debugger statement at the beginning of the script.